# Java Spring Error Handling Performance in Web Applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, error-handling

This is focused on backend web application development. I prefer to use HTTP status codes in my application that map to my business logic. An example being if a request is made and a user isn't found, I'll throw an exception and have it be handled with `@ControllerAdvice` or `@ExceptionHandler` and map to 404 not found. Sometimes I have these inside of try catch blocks for logging and re-throw the exception. I prefer this way because the implementer of the API can just look at the status code and move on, no need to deserialize if it's an expected client error. A colleague believes if it's an expected state of the application everything should mostly be 200 with the response body containing the reason of failure instead of the expected response object because executing the catch block is an expensive operation. I personally don't like that approach because the implementer of your API has to check the response entity and try and deserialize it to the expected object or if that fails deserialize it to some know exception object because it's always 200.

TLDR: My problem is I see a lot of articles on why executing catch blocks can be expensive depending on the stacktrace, and that error handling shouldn't be part of control flow, but I have a hard time agreeing with that because Spring has the functionality like `@ControllerAdvice` , `@ExceptionHandler` or the newer `ResponseStatusException`. I also don't agree with the argument that HTTP status codes refer to the protocol and that 200 just means successful transmission. If that's the case then 401 and 403 should be 200 because the response was processed fine the client just didn't have authorization or the right authorization. That argument says to me that everything should be 200 and why even use the other status codes? I'm still early in my career so please forgive if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Executing catch blocks is cheap; the only thing that's costly is filling in stack traces on new exception objects. And you're right that any 2xx response with something like `"error": true` is a violation of the express contract of HTTP; review [the long list of error codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) to demonstrate the kinds of things that are expected to be signaled via a 4xx.

Comment: Let's say in an example, a client makes a request for a user by id and the server doesn't find a user is that a 404 or a 200 with an empty response body? For me that is a 404 for my colleague that's a 200 tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4

Comment: `/users?id=1234` returns `[]` because a collection resource is multi-valued. `/users/1234` returns 404.

Comment: That makes sense. I still struggle with a proper response regarding using exceptions for control flow. You mention `the only thing that's costly is filling in stack traces on new exception objects` but that is part of flow of the application in order to invoke `@ControllerAdvice, etc so it will happen regularly.

Comment: In the Java part of your application (inside the Web boundary), use Design by Contract principles: APIs should explain preconditions, the expected input, postconditions, and return values. Exceptions are exactly that--_exceptions_ to the normal rules (like saying "I can't do that because the network failed" with an `IOException`). Deciding whether to use `null`, `Optional.empty()`, or `NotFoundException` is a matter of what makes sense in your business modeling, and don't conform your model to merely hypothetical performance criteria.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can't just skip try-catch block in every case. If your code throws some exception, you should be well aware of those known exceptions to fully handle for uninterrupted service or stop app from unexpected behavior. If you have to catch or handle exceptions, then catch it and handle it.

Regarding the cost of handling exception:

Never try to write too many business logic inside catch block. Just keep it simple and handle or propagate it. There is nothing to worry about the cost. In the server application, sometimes you have to trace the fault by catching exceptions and write proper log for that. Moreover, 'try' has almost no expense at all. Instead of doing the work of setting up the try at runtime, the code's metadata is structured at compile time such that when an exception is thrown, it now does a relatively expensive operation of walking up the stack and seeing if any try blocks exist that would catch this exception.

Regarding, HttpStatus Code:

Http will not force you to apply 200 as a successful status code. You can also use 401 or 403 as your response code. Http has some standards. Like (400 for bad request, 403 forbidden) If you don't follow it no harm. However, you are breaking the standards. For, an instance, you have provided me an API which returns JSON as a response. However, I am expecting 200 for my successful operation. If you set 401 as your success code, I will have to face some dilemmas to find the issues. So, its better you should follow the standards.

Comment: I'm confused you say "There is nothing to worry about the cost" and then in the same paragraph reference "relatively expensive operation of walking up the stack". Additionally with the 401 vs 200 scenario that is easy to identify but let's say in an example a client makes a request for a user by id and the server doesn't find a user is that a 404 or a 200 with an empty response body? For me that is a 404 for my colleague that's a 200 tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4

Comment: If you want to follow the standards, I would say, respond with a 404 code, not 200. If you do so, then the caller can easily identify that the id may not be in the system. And it is also a good idea to acknowledge the client with a proper error message along with status code. And the stack memory is relatively faster. You don't have to worry about it assuming that it is not flooded with recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole range of http status codes that should be used given the correct scenario. In my opinion 200 (Http.OK) should only be used for a successful response. If you are making a POST, I would usually make a 201 as this means Http.Created. In the event of an error you could make a Http.UNATHORISED (400) or any of the 400 and 500 series to indicate an error and then throw an exception. This is far more useful than throwing a 200 each time followed by an exception. Uncle Bob in clean code says you should always throw an exception not just a status code so your thinking is correct to an extent.

Comment: Thanks I've read clean code but it's been a while. I'll revisit that chapter.

Answer (score -1):

*a client makes a request for a user by id and the server doesn't find a user is that a 404 or a 200 with an empty response body?*

In the above case what you have mentioned, It should be 200. You need to use 404 when the URL is not found. Similarly in all your API's you can handle them in a generic manner, Positive - 200 or 201, Negative 500. 404 and other 4xx errors you can handle in your @ControllerAdvice or @Exceptional Handler classes. 
Sometimes, we also use 4xx in Authentication/Authorization.

Comment: You use a 404 when _the resource_ is not found. In this case, the user is the resource.

Comment: What about in the scenario the url is something like `/user/123` with the path variable being the user id? and what should be the response body if the client is expecting a user object to deserialize?

Comment: It's practically impossible to handle 404 and other 4xx errors in all the API's whether your client is Browser or Mobile.
In the above case you mentioned, the user with 123 id is not found. It should return a response code of 200 and with an empty object. The client has to handle if the object is empty.

Comment: From the project level point of view, all API's included, if we need some metadata with respect to every API, then, in that case, the resource will become the data and the metadata.